# How to mock a generic method to return concrete type?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, generics, mocking

I'm trying to mock the return type of a generic method to match a specific concrete type but I cannot seem to get the casting to work out:

[image]

```
    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(GenericIsAuthenticatedResponse) && key == "1234")
            return GetGenericIsAuthenticatedResponse();

        return default(T);
    }

    private static GenericIsAuthenticatedResponse GetGenericIsAuthenticatedResponse()
    {
       return new GenericIsAuthenticatedResponse
        {
            AuthCode = "1234",
            Email = "email@email.com"
        };
    }
```

So my question is how can I get the mock method to return the GenericIsAuthenticatedResponse?

Comment: Why do you want your method to be generic in this case?

Comment: Because it it used for various different types, I am testing only one very specific scenario.

Comment: Assuming that T will always be `GenericIsAuthenticatedResponse` in the test, you can simply cast the return value to `T` before returning it.

Comment: Try `return (T)(object)GetGenericIsAuthenticatedResponse();`

Answer (score 2):

That does not work because of how generics work. If you want to return a specific type, you need to provide a filter for `T`:

```
public T Get<T>(string key) where T: GenericIsAuthenticatedResponse
```

Otherwise, don't use generics for the return type:

```
public object Get<T>(string key)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(GenericIsAuthenticatedResponse) && key == "1234")
        return GetGenericIsAuthenticatedResponse();

    return default(T);
}
```

If you are completely sure that `T` will be `GenericIsAuthenticatedResponse` (given it's a test), you can do this:

```
public T Get<T>(string key)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(GenericIsAuthenticatedResponse) && key == "1234")
        return (T)GetGenericIsAuthenticatedResponse();

    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, but I don't want to change the method just to satisfy 1 specific test case.

Answer (score -2):

I applied some lateral thinking in the end (or bodge depending on your POV) and serialised/deserialised Json to achieve this:

```
   public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(GenericIsAuthenticatedResponse) && key == "1234")
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(GetGenericIsAuthenticatedResponse());

        return default(T);
    }

    private static string GetGenericIsAuthenticatedResponse()
    {
        var r = new GenericIsAuthenticatedResponse
        {
            Username = "email.email.com",
            AuthCode = "1234"
        };

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r);
    }
```

Comment: This will fail if `T` is anything but a `GenericIsAuthenticatedResponse`. If this was the case, you could have just done `(T)GetGenericIsAuthenticatedResponse()`

Comment: You don’t need to serialize and deserialize an object just to cast a reference.